# best way to create a flatlist with a button at the end? React Native with firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

pretty much just want to know the best way to create something of this nature:

[image: name of each card is decided by the user]

this is the firebase, note that the image is created in figma so this firebase isn't whats creating it. Main question is how do I make a button be in the last position of the flatlist?

[image]

Comment: you need to explain more, make a button in the end of scrollview is easy but dunno what u want with the firebase

Comment: Is your question about Flatlist or Firebase? I don't see how it can be about both.

Comment: probably should have been a bit clearer, the data is coming from firebase, each chapter is a document that is added when they click the add button. The question is how to add a button at the end of a flatlist or scrollview when the data is from firebase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a separate component with the button(s) you want to add at the end of the Flatlist.

Then call this component in the Flatlist's 'ListFooterComponent' prop.

This way at the end of the flatlist you will always find the buttons that you want there.

Here's an example:

```
<FlatList
    data={data}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <ListItemComponent />
    ListFooterComponent={() => <ButtonComponent />} // Add the button component here!
/>
```

The button component in the 'ListFooterComponent' prop of the flatlist contains the button that you want at the end of the flatList.

From the ReactNative FlatList docs:

> ListFooterComponent
>
> Rendered at the bottom of all the items. Can be a React Component
> Class, a render function, or a rendered element.

For more details you can check out the ReactNative Docs on [Flatlist](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#listfootercomponent)